# YoutubeDL starts Downloading the Whole playlist instead of just one Video

Tags: youtube-dl

i was trying to download a video from Youtube using Youtubedl. i downloaded one of the videos of that playlist just easily but on the second one when i try to download from its URL,YoutubeDL starts downloading the whole playlist. i am a nooby guys so any help would be great :)
url link is :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtdFPppcup4&list=PL9ooVrP1hQOH3SvcgkC4Qv2cyCebvs0Ik&index=3&t=0s

might be the URL problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at your URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtdFPppcup4&list=PL9ooVrP1hQOH3SvcgkC4Qv2cyCebvs0Ik&index=3&t=0s , you'll see it refers *both* to a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtdFPppcup4 *and* a playlist ( https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9ooVrP1hQOH3SvcgkC4Qv2cyCebvs0Ik ).

youtube-dl interprets this as a playlist by default, but you can force one of the two behaviors. In [youtube-dl's options](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#video-selection), you'll find

> `--no-playlist` Download only the video, if the URL refers a video and a playlist.
>   `--yes-playlist` Download the playlist, if the URL refers to video and a playlist.

So start youtube-dl as

```
youtube-dl --no-playlist "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtdFPppcup4&list=PL9ooVrP1hQOH3SvcgkC4Qv2cyCebvs0Ik&index=3&t=0s"
```

to get just the video. If you always want this behavior, consider [setting up a configuration file](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration).

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, [please consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!

Comment: Just did the accepting :) sry that i dunno the stuff,it seems like i can't Vote that answer up since i don't have that much reputation. again Thank you :) this Community is amazing.